# table with values above vertical lines and/or over

Tags: tables

I would like to be able to have a table like the one in the picture (hand drawn) below. I am not familiar with tikz, or proficient power latex user, and mostly use them by examples. If anyone can provide solutions, or at least, hints, how to approach a solution, it would be mostly welcomed.

The requirement is a table to use it for calculus. the vertical lines could be one or doubled (in case of the exact value excluded). The most difficult parts for me are, the values that should be centered above the vertical lines, like 2 and 3 in the example. Also the 0 crossing the vertical line. The infinity or other value (if specific range is used) should be at the left and right margin like the example.

for example for equation x^2+x-6=0
I tried with tables, but the result is not what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Out of curiosity: why the `2` and `3` should be above the lines?

Comment: @Alenanno `-3` and `2` are the zero points of function `f(x) = x^2 + x - 6`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ah it's `-3`. Thanks for the explanation.  :)

Comment: You can take a look at the comprehensive `tkz-tab` package, which is done precisely for that sort of things (tables of signs, of variations, &c.). Documentation in French.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an actual `tabular` environment, you can use `\tikzmark` and "fake" vertical rules (actual table columns).

Otherwise you can just draw a custom table entirely using Tikz. It's up to you and the use you'll make of this.

Note: you might need to run it twice if you see lines getting out of position (usually each time you change some value, run it twice).

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\DrawLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=-.2ex, shorten >=-.2ex,#1] (#2.north) -- (#3.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\renewcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] 
\node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};}

\begin{document}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{c|M{5mm}M{4mm}M{2mm}M{4mm}M{2mm}}
 $X$ & $-\infty$ & $-3$ & & 2 & \\ \hline
 $x^2+x-6$ & & \tikzmark{a}{$0$} & & \tikzmark{c}{$0$} & \\
  & $+$ & \tikzmark{b}{} & $-$ & \tikzmark{d}{} & $+$ 
\end{tabular}
    \DrawLine{a}{b}
    \DrawLine{c}{d}
\end{document}
```